# All possible NSNumber objCType

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsnumber

What are all the possible NSNumber Objective-C types and what is their meaning?

Looking at the NSNumber Class Reference I found the following:

> Your implementation of objCType must return one of “c”, “C”, “s”, “S”, “i”, “I”, “l”, “L”, “q”, “Q”, “f”, and “d”.

Where can I find the meaning of all those types?

Comment: encodings are found here - [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)

Comment: Do note that they play fairly fast and loose with those codes.  In particular, if the actual type of the object is NSDecimalNumber then the objCType value is not very reliable and you need to query the NSDecimalNumber characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Mac Developer Library:

To assist the runtime system, the compiler encodes the return and argument types for each method in a character string and associates the string with the method selector. The coding scheme it uses is also useful in other contexts and so is made publicly available with the @encode() compiler directive. When given a type specification, @encode() returns a string encoding that type. The type can be a basic type such as an int, a pointer, a tagged structure or union, or a class name—any type, in fact, that can be used as an argument to the C sizeof() operator.

You can find their meaning in the following link to:
[Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)